# Basic testing system implementation

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I've written a `BaseTestCase` class (which is meant to be inherited by all test cases) and a number of `TestCase<Number>(BaseTestCase)` classes (each in its own .py file).

The project structure is:

- BaseTestCase.py
- TestCase1.py
- TestCase2.py

Example:

```
class TestCase2(BaseTestCase):
    # methods

    def execute(self):
        self.method1()
        self.method2()
        self.method3()
```

The `execute` method should be called on an instance of `TestCase<Number>` to run a specific test. What is the proper way to run all test cases, i.e. to orchestrate them all?

Comment: maybe have a look at unittest and pytest?

Comment: _What is the proper way to run all test cases, i.e. to orchestrate them all?_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AMC How to select all TestCases and run them from a .py script effectively?

Comment: That's still really broad, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Unittest framework and want to run tests programmatically and have the ability to select which tests you run. If that's the correct assumption, here is the answer.

Lets assume you have those tests:

```py
class TestExample1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        pass

    def test_something_else(self):
        pass
```

```py
class TestExample2(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        pass

    def test_something_else(self):
        pass
```

If those are in the same file, you can simply run them like this

```py
# assuming your tests are above in this same file
unittest.main()
```

However, if they are in different files, you will have to extract the tests from them like so

```py
for example in [TestExample1, TestExample2]:
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(example)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(tests)
```

This will result in two different executions like this

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

If you are considering other frameworks for running your tests, I recommend to take a look at Test Junkie: https://www.test-junkie.com/get-started/ as its much easier to get started with and is very powerful. (disclaimer: I'm the author!).